# Comparing file paths using Levenshtein Distance

Tags: java, c#, algorithm, comparison, string-comparison

I need to figure out how close specific file paths are, the Levenshtein distance algorithm works great, but I need to somehow give weightings to directories that are higher up the directory tree.

For example:

My source is "x:/t/c/d"

And my two targets are:

- "a:/t/c/d"
- "x:/t/y/z"

I need the second target to identify as being closer even though "as a string" it's edit distance is greater (since target two is in the same parent directory "x" as the source, whilst the first target is looking at directory "a".

How would I go about giving a weighting to characters that appear earlier on in the strings?

Comment: why did someone give this a down vote? feel like the problem is sensical, the person looked up the Levenshtein distance and has applied it, so not sure what the downvote is for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me the *Levenshtein Distance* on the full path is not the right algorithm for what you are trying to achieve.

I would suggest you to split the path into a list of folder (eventually with a file on the end), then I would compare the directory name (or drive) at the corresponding position and give to that a high score if it is a perfect match, lowering the score as you go further down the directory tree.

If it's not a match, than you could still apply the Levenshtein Distance on the path and multiply it for a weight which would decrease as well as you go further down.

Than sum it all up.

For example:

```
var source = "x:/t/c/d";
var targets = new[] { "a:/t/c/d", "x:/t/y/z" };

var separator = '/';
var sourceParts = source.Split(separator);
var weight = 10;
var match = 100;

var scores = targets.Select(target =>
{
    var score = sourceParts
        .Zip(target.Split(separator), (s, t) => new Tuple<string, string>(s, t))
        .Select(
            (tuple, i) => tuple.Item1 == tuple.Item2
                ? match * GetWeight(i)
                : LevenshteinDistance(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2) * GetWeight(i)
        ).Sum();

    return new
    {
        Target = target,
        Score = score
    };
});
```

where GetWeight() is something like:

```
private static int MaxWeight = 10;
private static int GetWeight(int i) => i < MaxWeight ? MaxWeight - i : 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

How about splitting both the source and the targets usind "/", and then compare each one of them separately, that way the second one should be the one closer

**C# Code:**

```
        var source = "x:/t/c/d";
        var sourceSplitted = source.Split('/');
        List<string> targets = new List<string>() { "a:/t/c/d", "x:/t/y/z" };

        for (int i = 0; i < sourceSplitted.Length; i++)
        {
            foreach (var item in targets)
            {
                var targetSplitted = item.Split('/');
                // Calculate levenshtein here using sourceSplitted[i] and targetSplitted[i]
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Would suggest splitting up the path and giving it an inverse weight starting from the back, psuedocode would be:

```
currPath = null
currMin = int.Max


for (path in paths){ 

    var curr = 0

    var idx = 1;

    for ( x in Inverse( Split ( path ) ) ) { 

        curr+= idx * LevenshteinDistance( x )
        idx++;
    }

    if(idx < currMin)
        currPath = path;        
}
```

for very long paths where everything matched then it might not work but that is an issue you are going to run into with any "guessing" algorithms, but something like that should cover your needs